# How to trigger a mouseout event in Python Dash?

Tags: python, callback, mouseover, plotly-dash, mouseout

How can I implement a callback function that reacts to `mouseout` and restores a default when not hovering over a data point?

I simplified a code snipped from the 'Interactive Visualizations' section of the Plotly|Dash tutorial to illustrate my question. In this example a `callback` function returns the `mouseover` information. How do I return a default on `mouseout`?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1,2,1,2],
    "y": [1,2,3,4]
})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y") 
fig.update_traces(marker_size=20)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='basic-interactions',
        figure=fig
    ),
    html.Div([
        html.Pre(id='hover-data')
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('hover-data', 'children'),
    Input('basic-interactions', 'hoverData'))
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    if hoverData:
        return str(hoverData)
    else:
        return "hover over data point"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `clear_on_unhover` property on [`dcc.Graph`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph):

> clear_on_unhover (boolean; default False): If True, clear_on_unhover will clear the hoverData property when the user "unhovers" from a point. If False, then the hoverData property will be equal to the data from the last point that was hovered over.

So change this:

```
dcc.Graph(id="basic-interactions", figure=fig)
```

to this:

```
dcc.Graph(id="basic-interactions", figure=fig, clear_on_unhover=True)
```

On unhover `hoverData` will be equal to `None`, so the callback in the example can stay unchanged. `"hover over data point"` will be returned on unhover.